# How to calculate prices in javascript after removing input rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this sounds ridiculous but I need to calculate my invoice prices after removing a row. I followed the javascript portion of a php tutorial from Weblesson Invoice. This is my javacript code for removing:

```
$(document).on('click','.remove_row',function(){
  var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var total_service_amount = $('#quote_service_actual_amount'+row_id).val();
  var sub_amount = $('#subtotal_amount').text();
  var tax_rate = $('#tax_rate').text();
  var tax_amount = $('#tax_amount').text();
  var final_amount = $('#final_total_amt').text();
  var result_amount = parseFloat(final_amount) - parseFloat(total_service_amount);
  $('#final_total_amt').text(result_amount);
  $('#row_id_'+row_id).remove();
  count = count - 1;
  $('#total_service').val(count);
});
```

And this is for calculating when adding rows:

```
 function cal_final_total(count){
  var final_service_total = 0;
  var subtotal = 0;
  var tax_rates = 0;
  var tax_amt = 0;
  for(j=1; j<=count; j++)
  {
    var hours = 0;
    var rates = 0;
    var actual_amount = 0;

    rates = $("#quote_service_rates"+j).val();
    if(rates > 0){
      hours = $("#quote_service_hours"+j).val();
      if(hours > 0){
        actual_amount = parseFloat(rates) * parseFloat(hours);
        $("#quote_service_actual_amount"+j).val(actual_amount);
      }
    }
  }

  //Calculate subtotal
  $(".quote_service_actual_amount").each(function(){
    subtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    // subtotal -= parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $("#subtotal_amount").val(subtotal.toFixed(2));

  //Calculate tax total
  tax_rates = $("#tax_rate").val();
  if(tax_rates > 0){
    tax_amt = parseFloat(tax_rates)/100 * parseFloat(subtotal);
    $("#tax_amount").val(tax_amt.toFixed(2));
  }

  //Calculate final amount
  final_service_total = parseFloat(subtotal) + parseFloat(tax_amt);
  $("#final_total_amt").val(Math.round(final_service_total * 100)/100);
}
```

My table structure:

```
<table id="quote_service_table" class="table table-bordered" name="serviceTable">
                <tr>
                  <th>Sr No.</th>
                  <th>Service</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Service Rates(RM)</th>
                  <th>Hours</th>
                  <th>Total Amount(RM)</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row_id_1">
                  <td>
                    <span id="quote_sr_no" name="quote_sr_no">1</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="quote_service_type[]" autocomplete="off" id="quote_service_type1" class="form-control input-sm quote_service_type" list="type" required/>
                    <!-- <datalist id="type">
                    </datalist> -->
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="quote_service_description[]" autocomplete="off" id="quote_service_description1" list="descript" class="form-control input-sm quote_service_description" required/>
                    <!-- <datalist id="descript">
                    </datalist> -->
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="quote_service_rates[]" autocomplete="off" data-srno="1" id="quote_service_rates1" class="form-control input-sm number_only quote_service_rate" required/>
                    <!-- <datalist id="rate">
                    </datalist> -->
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="quote_service_hours[]" autocomplete="off" data-srno="1" id="quote_service_hours1" class="form-control input-sm number_only quote_service_hours" list="hour" required/>
                    <!-- <datalist id="hour">
                    </datalist> -->
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="quote_service_actual_amount[]" autocomplete="off" data-srno="1" id="quote_service_actual_amount1" class="form-control input-sm number_only quote_service_actual_amount" required readonly />
                  </td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <div align="right">
                <input type="button" id="add_row" name="add_row" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" value="+"/>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="right">
            <td><label style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:right;width:600px" for="subtotal_amount">Subtotal:</td></td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="subtotal_amount" name="subtotal_amount" class="form-control number_only input-sm subtotal_amount" readonly/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="right">
            <td><label style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:right;width:600px" for="tax_rate">Tax Rate(%):</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="tax_rate" name="tax_rate" class="form-control number_only input-sm tax_rate" value="5" readonly/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="right">
            <td><label style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:right;width:600px" for="tax_amount">Tax Total:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="tax_amount" name="tax_amount" class="form-control number_only input-sm tax_amount" readonly/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="right">
            <td><label style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;text-align:right;width:600px" for="final_total_amt"><b>Estimated Total: RM</b></td></td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="final_total_amt" name="final_total_amt" class="form-control number_only input-sm final_total_amt" readonly/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
          </tr>
```

Now, calculating to add total I have no problem, but subtracting I'm having trouble. I though of ignoring this problem but it has been gnawing at my mind. Any help is appreciated.

[Invoice table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGqhn.png)

Comment: Could you please provide your table structure that will be very easy to provide the solution

Comment: I don't think you have to do as much as you are doing stright forward solution is bind class name with all the TD's which should be same. then you can get all the tds with class name just add the values of that